# django datefield filter

Tags: python, django, datetime, filter

I'd like to use an object filter similar to the following

```
Shipment.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.date(2005,1,1))
```

However there doesn't seem to be support for comparison operators on datetime objects. Is there a method I'm unaware of or should I look into writing a custom filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use date comparison in my code a lot and they work e.g copied  a snippet from my calendar code

```
q.filter(start_date__gt=pay_period.start_date).order_by("start_date")
```

Comment: Really sorry I must be so tired, I've been trying to get this to work in one view function while accessing the url of a separate function... sorry to waste your time thank you for the quick response